# While making responsive website which CSS we should keep outside media queries? Smaller one or bigger one?

Tags: css, browser

I'm making a website which has 3 breakpoint 768px, 1024px and 1900 px. Which size of CSS is good to keep outside media query containers?

## Adding example

**All specific styling inside media queries and all common styling outside**

```
h1 {color:red}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
h1 {font-size:18px}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
h1 {font-size:22px}

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
h1 {font-size:28px}

}
```

or

**Most common used desktop first**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024x) {
h1 {font-size:28px; font-color:red}

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
h1 {font-size:18px}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
h1 {font-size:22px; }

}
```

or

**Mobile first**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
h1 {font-size:18px; font-color:red}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024x) {
h1 {font-size:28px; }

}


@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
h1 {font-size:22px; }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question but currently a viewport around 1000px is most common.. So keep 1024px as default? I'd prefer a 978 or 960 pixelgrid though (see 960.gs 978gs websites for more information)

Comment: I select 1024px. because most monitors are widely used resolution 1028 x 800 or 1360 x 768  :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you mean to ask what CSS should not be inside of the media query blocks, right?

If that is the case I recommend that any CSS that does not change be placed outside of the media query blocks. Any colors, font styling, etc. Any CSS that changes placement of elements, the padding, floats, inline or block display types, any structure-type CSS is what I would put in the media query blocks.

**Update:** To respond to the updated question, are you asking which order you should put the media blocks in? If that's the case as far as I know it doesn't really matter what order they go in. But to comment on the number of possible media queries, I would separate that CSS into different style sheets just to make it more maintainable. Your media queries would then be a part of the links to your style sheets in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to approach this problem - and the decision may be different depending on the circumstances. For example, is there an existing site that you are reverse engineering to be responsive or are you starting from scratch?

**STARTING FROM SCRATCH**

If starting from scratch, one method is to create all of the basic styles OUTSIDE of any media query - so that these styles can be seen by any device (especially those devices that do not support media queries).

Basic styles could include just colors, and fonts etc - or it could be everything except layout.

Then, media queries are used to add the different layouts on top of the basic styles.

**MIN or MIN AND MAX**

The next question is how will you work your different media queries...

Will you allow them to be applied on top of one another - in which case you may start small and build up - using min-width only.

For example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)
```

OR you may want to set them in a series of brackets - so that styes for one size do not interact with another size.

For example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 800px)
```

Again, there is no right or wrong - both have strengths and weaknesses. The first option allows you to use styles that flow through all widths. The second option allows you to fully control styles that appear in a specific width - without having to deal with the cascade.

**DEALING WITH IE**

There are a range of ways for dealing with older versions of IE including.

1. allow IE to see basic styles only
2. place media queries in separate CSS files and link to these files using media queries... then also link to a selection of these files (like wide screen CSS files only) via conditional comments.
3. Use some sort of JS solution like respond.js or others to force IE to understand the media queries.

HTH

Comment: +1 Thanks Russ. If we start from Scratch then Luke suggest to go for Mobile First approach. is it mean that in that case Mobile styling should be outside media queries and then media queries for tablets and desktop?

Comment: Yes, ideally. Many mobiel devices do not support media queries at all. So, these devices should be served the basic styles - the ones before all other styles inside media queries.

Answer (score 0):

I've read many articles recently that suggest starting with the smallest resolution first and working your way upwards using media queries. To me that also makes a lot of sense. The only problem is old browsers (IE) not understanding media queries. There are solutions to that problem though (if you Google).